# Django get_signed_cookie on manually signed cookie

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm using `get_signed_cookie` in one of my views, and it works. The problem is in testing it, i'm manually signing my cookie in my test using Django's `django.core.signing` module with the same salt as my actual code (i'm using a salt that's in my `settings`).

When i do non-automated tests, all is well. I've compared the cookie that is set in my test with the cookie that is set by Django itself and they're the same structure:

In my test (I'm manually signing the string 'test_cookie_value' in my test):

`{'my_cookie': 'test_cookie_value:s5SA5skGmc4As-Weyia6Tlwq_V8'}`

Django:

`{'my_cookie': 'zTmwe4ATUEtEEAVs:1YRl0a:Lg3KHfpL93HoUijkZlNphZNURu4'}`

But when my view tries to `get_signed_cookie("my_cookie", False, salt="my_salt")`, `False` is returned.

I think this is strange, and while i'm trying to obey the testing goat (first time TDD'er here) i'm tempted to skip testing this..

I hope someone can give me some guidance, i'm stuck ignoring the goat noises in the background for now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found my solution. It was rather straightforward actually.

I tried to set my cookie on my request for the test, which made sense since the cookie should be sent in the request. A better way of testing it is to just `GET` a resource first (which sets te cookie, which would happen in a normal web-situation as well) and then `POST` with the set cookie. This worked just fine.

Comment: The testing goat would like to see the actual code that comprised the solution :)